# Error passing argument1 of 'fprintf' from incompatible pointer type. C

Tags: c, data-structures

here is what i have so far. The only building issue is line 95, the last line of code. I'm trying to count the lines in a file, then build arrays from the data and display arrays of max and min values form user inputs.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"



struct earthquake_t
{ 
    float lat;
    float lng;
    float dep;
    float mag;
};

FILE* fid;

int main(void)
{
    double lat,lng, dep,mag;
    double userminlat,userminlng,usermaxlat,usermaxlng,minlat,minlng,maxlat,maxlng,                      ch,line,count
    struct earthquake_t *earthquake;
    int i;


    fid=fopen("day.txt","r");

    while (!feof(fid))
    {

         line = fscanf(fid,"%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n",&lng,&lat,&dep,&mag);
         count = fscanf(fid," %lf %lf %lf %lf\n",&lng,&lat,&dep,&mag);


        if (count ==4)
        {
             line ++;
        }
    }

    fseek(fid,1,SEEK_SET);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct earthquake_t));          
    earthquake = (struct earthquake_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct earthquake_t)*line);

    for (i=0;i<line;i++)
    {          
        sscanf("fid", "%lf %lf %lf %lf\n",&lng,&lat,&dep,&mag,
        earthquake[i].lat,
        earthquake[i].lng,
        earthquake[i].dep,
        earthquake[i].mag);

        if(earthquake[i].lng >maxlng) 
        {     
            maxlng = earthquake[i].lng;
        }
        if(earthquake[i].lng >minlng)
        {    
            minlng = earthquake[i].lng;
        }
        if(earthquake[i].lat >maxlat)
        {
            maxlat = earthquake[i].lat;
        }
        if(earthquake[i].lat >minlat)
        {

        minlat = earthquake[i].lat;
        }

    } 



    printf("Longitude is between %f and %f\n",minlng,maxlng);
    printf("Latitude is between %f and %f\n\n",minlat,maxlat);
    printf("Give a value for min longitude: ");
    scanf("%d",userminlng);
    printf("Give a value for max longitude: ");
    scanf("%d",usermaxlng);
    printf("Give a value for min latitude: ");
    scanf("%d",userminlat);
    printf("Give a value for max latitude: ");
    scanf("%d",usermaxlat);


    FILE *fid2;
    fid2=fopen("subset.txt","w");

    for (i=0;i<line;i++)
    {     
        if((earthquake[i].lng > userminlng) && (earthquake[i].lng < usermaxlng))
        {    
            if((earthquake[i].lat > userminlat) && (earthquake[i].lat < userminlat))
            {
                fprintf( "subset.txt" ,"%f,%f,%f,%f \n", earthquake[i].lat,              earthquake[i].lng, earthquake[i].dep, earthquake[i].mag); //error

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int fprintf ( **FILE * stream**, const char * format, ... );

Answer (score 8):

`fprintf` takes a `FILE *` pointer as its first argument.  In this case, you probably wanted to pass in `fid2`.

Comment: Just add it as the first argument instead of the name of the file, as in `fprintf(fid2, "%f,%f,%f,%f\n", ...)`.